# Integrality of primary genus $0$ Gromov-Witten invariants of a Fano manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, intersection-theory, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Suppose $(X,\omega)$ is a positively monotone compact symplectic manifold, i.e., after a positive scaling of the symplectic form, we have $c_1(T_X) = [\omega]$ in de Rham cohomology ($T_X$ has well-defined Chern classes as it is a symplectic vector bundle). Then, McDuff-Salamon in their book "$J$-holomorphic Curves and Symplectic Topology" show that we can define genus $0$ Gromov-Witten invariants (abbreviated below as GW) for $X$ by choosing a generic $\omega$-compatible (or $\omega$-tame) almost complex structure and showing that the (top stratum of the) moduli space gives a manifold (and not orbifold) pseudo-cycle of the expected dimension. This has the consequence that the genus $0$ GW invariants of $X$ evaluated on integral (co)homology classes pulled back from $X$ are integers (and not merely rational numbers).

A special case of monotone symplectic manifolds are Fano manifolds, i.e., smooth complex projective varieties $X$ with ample anticanonical bundle $-K_X$. For these, we can use the algebro-geometric definition of genus 0 GW invariants (following Behrend-Fantechi's paper "Intrinsic Normal Cone") and we may ask the same question. Namely, **for a Fano manifold $X$, homology class $\beta\in H_2(X,\mathbb Z)$ and integer $n\ge 0$, is the pushforward $\text{ev}_*[\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n}(X,\beta)]^\text{vir}$ of the (algebro-geometric) virtual fundamental class under the evaluation map $\text{ev}:\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n}(X,\beta)\to X^n$ an integral class in the Chow group $A_*(X^n,\mathbb Q)$?**

**Is there a reference for an algebro-geometric proof of the above statement (in particular, is it a true statement)?** Heuristically, the statement should be true because we expect that McDuff-Salamon and Behrend-Fantechi's definitions agree on Fano manifolds (I would also like to know a reference where this is proved rigorously).